# How to connect with socketio build in laravel >laravel-echo-server, from nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

***First Approch*: Using `laravel Echo` from *node* side**

I'm trying to connect **socketio** server using `laravel-Echo` package from **nodejs**
as follwing:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const ioClient = require("socket.io-client");
// const socketio = require("socket.io");
const Echo = require("laravel-echo");

this.echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: 'localhost' + ':' + 6001,
   client: ioClient,
   logToConsole: true,
   transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
});
console.log(echo);

this.echo.channel('close-flare').listen('.CloseFlareEvent', data => {
   console.log(data);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));
module.exports = app;
```

when I `console.log(this.echo)` object inside **node** console returned as follows:

```
Echo {
   options: {
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host: 'localhost:6001',
     client: <ref *1> [Function: lookup] {
       managers: [Object],
       io: [Circular *1],
       protocol: [Getter],
       connect: [Circular *1],
       Manager: [Getter]
     },
     logToConsole: true,
     transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket' ]
   },
   connector: SocketIoConnector {
     _defaultOptions: {
       auth: [Object],
       authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
       broadcaster: 'socket.io',
       csrfToken: null,
       host: 'localhost:6001',
       key: null,
       namespace: 'App.Events',
       client: [Function],
       logToConsole: true,
       transports: [Array],
       path: '/socket.io',
       hostname: 'undefined',
       secure: false,
       port: '80'
     },
     options: {
       auth: [Object],
       authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
       broadcaster: 'socket.io',
       csrfToken: null,
       host: 'localhost:6001',
       key: null,
       namespace: 'App.Events',
       client: [Function],
       logToConsole: true,
       transports: [Array],
       path: '/socket.io',
       hostname: 'undefined',
       secure: false,
       port: '80'
     },
     socket: Socket {
       receiveBuffer: [],
       sendBuffer: [],
       ids: 0,
       acks: {},
       flags: {},
       io: [Manager],
       nsp: '//localhost:6001',
       connected: false,
       disconnected: true,
       auth: [Object],
       subs: [Array],
       _callbacks: [Object]
     },
     channels: {}
   }
 }
```

but the problem that when I send an event from **laravel** it doesn't come in the **node** server. However, I do get the event message if I call it from the **browser-side** as follows:

this code works well on the **browser-side**:

```
const Echo = require("laravel-echo");
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "socket.io",
  host: window.location.hostname + ":" + 6001,
  logToConsole: true,
  transports: ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
});
console.log(window.Echo);
window.Echo.channel("close-flare").listen(
  ".CloseFlareEvent",
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

php >laravel establishing code:

this code establishes the channel and the event inside larvel

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CloseFlareByTrader implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $flare_id;

    public function __construct($flare_id)
    {
        $this->flare_id = $flare_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('close-flare');
    }

    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'CloseFlareEvent';
    }

    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['flare_id' => $this->flare_id];
    }
}
```

***Second Approch*: Trying to use `WebSocket` instead of `laravel Echo` inside `node`**

If I tried to connect the socket using WebSocket as follow:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
var ws = new WebSocket("http://localhost:6001/socket.io?transport=websocket");
```

I get the following error on the **node side**:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:607:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ahmad\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:579:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

And in the **laravel-echo-server**  I get:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `react-native`. I wanted to connect to a `laravel-echo` server. `larave-echo-server` was working fine and was sending signals on the client side of larave but could not get signals in react native.
This is my react-native with `larave-echo` and `socket.io-client` setup

```
useEffect(() => {
  const echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: `wss://${host}:6001`,
    client: io,
  });

  const channel = echo.channel('trading-signal');
  channel.listen('TradingSignalEvent', e => {
    console.log('Received trading signal:', e.trading_signal);
    if (e.trading_signal) {
      setTradingSignal(e.trading_signal)
    }
  });
  echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Successfully connected.');
  });

  echo.connector.socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
  });
  // Cleanup function
  return () => {
    console.log('stopListening')
    channel.stopListening('TradingSignalEvent');
    echo.disconnect();
  };
}, []);
```

Import at the top:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

My problem was that I used different socket.io package versions on react-native side from backend. When I downgraded on react-native to:

```
"socket.io": "^2.5.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.5.0"
```

it started working.

Also you should check if you have correctly configured `larave-echo-server.json` file. For https(wss) you need to declare ssl certificate path.

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem",
    "sslKeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```